# Can I make page-unique headers/footers in MS Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word, header, footer

I'm writing VBA to process MS Word documents, and I need it to examine the contents of individual pages and generate related header/footer text from that. Is there a way to do this without creating new Sections?

I need the document to flow as it should, unbroken by Sections, but I also need (some of) the header/footer text to be distinct, per page. I know this is unusual due to auto-flowing pagination, etc. But, it really is necessary in this case; pieces of the header/footer must tie directly to each page's contents. That said, it may not be mandatory to have the text actually inside the "proper" header/footer; but, I do need the end result to be to that same effect.

Any tips? Can headers/footers be used for this? (In my research, it appears they may not be able to, although I may be missing something. Any other tips, if not? Perhaps some sort of special field/box?)

Note: Obviously, running this code would be a final step (once the document is in final form) since any editing of the document would re-flow its layout, modifying page contents.

Comment: What kind of information do you need to appear in the header/footer?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use sections, you can use conditional `IF` fields like this:

```
{IF { PAGE } = 2 "Second Page" "Other Page" }
```

Note that you need to create nested fields for that, e.g. by pressing Ctrl+F9.

Comment: I'm assuming that'd go straight into the header/footer (rather than the VBA code)?Hmmm... Is it possible to call a macro from a field like that to scan the page's contents to then determine the text that will go there (to include formatting it)? The text can be thought of as anything, but it is directly dependent upon the actual page's text contents. Derived from it. It doesn't particularly have anything to do with any specific page number, just what's on the page.

Comment: @JJEII: It completely depends how the header is derived from the page. If you are able to just put a bookmark on each page around the part of text that also should appear in the header, you can put a cross-ref field in the header like so: `{ REF "MyBookmark{ PAGE } }"` where the name of the bookmark on each page would be "MyBookmark1", "MyBookmark2" etc.

Comment: If a bookmark is not suitable, you could also create a document variable for each page in the document that contains the header for the respective page.

Comment: My aim is to leave the main doc untouched & place per-page headers based on its contents. There are no special markers, fields, etc. It's entirely based on visible text contents. (Although, I've run into difficulties with tables...) Right now, I have a makeshift version somewhat working; it employs text boxes. But, they're not really what I want because they have anchors, which means if the doc changes, they move around with it. I want something that stays welded in place no matter what, and I can change the contents as needed. I don't know enough about doc vars to know if they'd work or how.

Comment: By the way, I really appreciate the feedback. Thank you.

Comment: @JJEII: Your requirements are very vague. If you come up with a concrete example I might be able to help.

Comment: There are too many details to go into, but a good stand-in is this (pp.14-15):
https://www.fas.org/sgp/othergov/dod/nimaguide.pdf
In my case, the paragraph-marking analog is just part of the regular text flow, not special Word fields (nothing meta). I already have functional code written to detect it. I just need a good way to stick it to each page, uniquely.

(Doc vars look like they may have some promise. Can they be arrays? How complex can field code be? Can font styles be adjusted, e.g. bold or differently colored, per-page? Hmmm... Researching...)

Comment: I've continued to work on this, and doc vars can definitely work for the basic contents at the page top, but I also need to vary the formatting from page to page (which I failed to identify as a separate requirement, e.g. font family, size, color, face, whatever). Is there a way to do that as well, and specifically in conjunction with doc vars? If so, I think that'll be the final, ideal solution. (So far, I haven't figured out how, though.)

Comment: I'm still hoping to figure out the formatting issue because the document variables suggestion looks really great if I can figure out the formatting part! (especially varying colors from page to page) Right now, though, I'm stumped on how to accomplish that---if it's even feasible.